# `try ... except not` construction

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-catch

Recently I met an example of code I've never seen before:

```py
try:
    # a simple bunch of code
    if sample == 0:
        return True
    else:
        raise ExampleError()
except not ExampleError:
    raise AnotherExampleError()
```

How does it work (if it works at all)?

Comment: Do you recall where you met this example and can you share this with us? The context might clear things up a bit. Was it working code, or maybe a proposal?

Comment: The python2.7 interpreter performs a logical `not` on your class `ExampleError` which evaluates to boolean `False`, and when you pass `False` to `except`, it appears to either be a No-operation, or otherwise in theory it would handle the situation where the user raises `False` in the try block. Which may actually be possible, if you're able to find a way to get python `False` to extend Exception.  We're going to need to escalate to Guido with this, entitled: "excuse me what the fu*k?"  Python duck typing strikes again with a surprise left jab.  POW!

Comment: @EricLeschinski Wasn't actually sure but it seems you can only raise subtypes of `BaseException` or old-style classes in Python 2. I tried to trigger that except block redefining `__eq__` in a class to return `True` when `False` was given but it didn't work, but Python being Python there may be a way to get into that block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: The answer below was for Python 3, I didn't realise the question related to Python 2.7. in Python 2, as it seems, the interpreter does not complain if the expression after `except` does not result in a subtype of `BaseException`. However, the behavior is still wrong, it will just ignore that `except` block in all cases.

---

That's a funny construction that is syntactically valid but semantically wrong. I suppose the author of the code meant to express something like "run this `except` block for any exception type but `ExampleError`". However, what is really happening is more like:

```
try:
    # ...
except (not bool(ExampleError)):
    # ...
```

When an exception is raised in the `try` block, Python goes through the different `except` blocks looking for one that matches the exception type. When it sees `except not ExampleError`, equivalent to `except (not bool(ExampleError))`, it results in `except False`, which is invalid because `False` is not a subtype of `BaseException` (or a tuple of subtypes of `BaseException`). So the code may even run if no exceptions are raised but is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to be successful on any version of Python as far as I know. Because the not operator always results in a Boolean value (`True` or `False`) this is trying to catch one of those values here, in this case `False`. Since you can't throw `True` or `False` there's no use for this.

I think the intent of the author was something like this:

```
try:
    raise ExampleError()
except ExampleError e:
    throw e
except:
    raise AnotherExampleError()
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick test shows that the code will throw a TypeError if it reaches that line:

```
try:
  raise BaseException
except not BaseException:
  print("Test1")
except BaseException:
  print("Test2")
```

Exception:

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 3, in
>   
>       except not BaseException: TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Comment: If that were the case then this question should be closed as not reproducible.

Comment: The above TypeError occurs when running the code with python 3, but not when running with python 2.7.

Comment: @Xukrao I suppose 2.7 doesn't do a type check of the class? So it's valid, but doesn't actually do anything.